# How do I update a setting in the global configuration scope from a vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension and I want to update one of its settings in the application scope.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```js
workspace.getConfiguration('my-extension', <some-scope>).update('some-setting', 'off');
```

Normally, calling this API method will update the settings value in the workspace scope, but the `getConfiguration` method takes an optional, second argument for the scope. The documentation describes how to set the scope for specific workspace folders, or languages, but it does not say how to specify a global scope.

How do I programmatically update a setting for the global scope?

Comment: is there something in particular from [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#:~:text=update(section%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20any%2C%20configurationTarget%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7C%20ConfigurationTarget%2C%20overrideInLanguage%3F%3A%20boolean)%3A%20Thenable%3Cvoid%3E) that is unclear to you?

Comment: @starball, yes to both questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the **Global / User settings** you must define the third parameter in the `update` function. No need to deal with that *scope* param in the `getConfiguration` part.

Something like:

```js
   workspace.getConfiguration(“my-extension”).update(“some-setting”, “off”, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
```

Hope this helps